# How do I activate a "God Mode" cheat in Portal?

Tags: cheats, portal

I just got into playing Portal recently and learned about a command console hidden and found the button to activate it. I have learned how to make cubes and stuff which helped me out a lot during a few levels.

But I wondered: "Is there any god mode in this game?". This got me thinking and I put "god" in the console. It came back as an invalid command. Is there something specific I need to type in the console? Or is this "god mode" too much to hope for in Portal?

(Note: I am only talking about Portal 1, I have never played Portal 2)

Comment: What do you mean by "god mode"? Specifically, what abilities would you expect to gain by enabling "god mode"?

Comment: @murgatroid99 Things like not dying in Toxic Water. Sorry if I didn't clarify, but God Mode is where you can never die and you can spawn things infinitely

Comment: this should not have been downvoted.  I thought almost everyone who plays video games knows what god mode is.  +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [cheatcc](https://www.cheatcc.com/pc/portalcheatscodes.html) it's not just typing `god` in the console

> Enter the options menu, select "Controls", then "Advanced". Turn on the option for the console. Then while playing the game, press ~ to display the console window. Type "sv_cheats 1" to enable cheat mode. Then, type one of the following codes and press [Enter] at the console window to activate the corresponding cheat function:

according to the link, God Mode is just `god`. there is also `buddha` which allows you to take damage but not die.

Keep in mind though that some hazards such as the toxic water, you dying in meant to help you get out as if you could survive in the toxic water in some levels, you would be suck and unable to get out. you may be able to get around this by using `sv_gravity [number]` which changes gravity with 600 being the default

Comment: Got it to work, thanks for your input